# What is the difference between these following assignments?

Tags: python-3.x

Example1:

```
>>>a,b='a-b','a-b'
>>>a is b
True
```

Example2:

```
>>>a='a-b';b='a-b'
>>>a is b
False
```

Here Example1 and Example2 show different results. 
Can anybody explain to me why it is happening like this?

Comment: In jupyternotebook i get this output

Comment: @VineethSai Try entering the assignment from example 1 first, then entering the assignment from example 2.

Comment: You can also have a look at [The internals of Python string interning](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/)

Answer (score 2):

`is` operator checks for the identity of the variable. i.e the `id(var)`. And `is` operator doesn't check for equality it checks for identity. So in your case both are variables are pointing to the same memory location. You can see that by using `id`.

```
>>> a='a-b';b='a-b'
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a)
2885821331920
>>> id(b)
2885821331920
```

So Python is just using the same memory location for both the `immutable` variables instead of creating a new one to reduce memory waste.

And for your case, in the first example it assigned the same identity and for the second Example it didn't assign the same identity.

And once you change the variable's value it's memory location is changed and this happens..

```
>>> b = 'new' # Changing value
>>> id(a)
2885821331920
>>> id(b)
2885782761064
>>> a is b
False
```

If you properly want to test for equality you might be better off with `==` operator.

Comment: I checked in jupyter notebook, the output is shown as in the question.

Comment: I checked in jupyter notebook, after repeating,   id('a-b')   statement, id is continuously changing. but in command prompt the value is always same. The output of above question i asked is complete opposite in command prompt.

Comment: @Abd Seems like the anaconda interpreter (the one that your jupyter is using) has different memory management system than the one in your computer.

Comment: After checking  a='a-b';b='a-b' statement, please check again with b='a-b' instead of b='new'. Here id(b) changes. Why?